# Is there any free C++ and/or C# compiler that runs on an Android-enabled Tablet PC?

Tags: c#, android, c++, ide

The question is not about writing C++ for Android, it's about writing C++ on Android.

I have an Android-enabled Tablet PC and I need to do both C++ and C# programming.

Is there any free C++ and/or C# compiler that runs on any Android-enabled Tablet PC?

I do not want to develop Android apps on PC.

I want to do my programming on an IDE that runs on Android.

Comment: Like CommonsWare mentioned there really is no such thing....at the moment. But I have seen in the android market an application that lets you write native apps right on an android device although I cant remember the name of it and dont know if it actually worked. I came across it in the market when I was searching for logcat related applications. But Im just curious....why would you need or want to build applications on an android device when it would be easier just to do it right on a pc or mac. Also Ive never heard of any IDE that runs directly on an android device.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify which OS/processor your C++ code will target to help clarify the question.

Comment: @MerickOWA, So you think Android isn't an OS, isn't it? And what processor most Android-enabled Tablet PCs use? A** (all capital). Guess the answer.

Comment: @Saqib Sorry, I misunderstood then, you said the question wasn't about writting "for Android" so I assume you were writing C++ code to run on a different processor/OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It exists in some form, at least. I have managed to find an application that even compiles C and Delphi without any extra dependencies (I assume it comes with GCC and FreePascal.) I can't find it at the moment, but keep searching. In the meantime, [TouchQode](http://www.touchqode.com/) at least will give you some scripting support. For C#, you'll need Mono. <s>The runtime for Mono is certainly available on Android and I see absolutely no reason there can't be a compiler for it on Android as well.</s> edit: As CommonWares mentions, there is no freely available Mono port for Android, so none of this applies. Pity.

Comment: MonoDroid is most certainly not free.

Comment: That's true. I thought another port of Mono was being worked on, but it certainly doesn't look like that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been nice if MonoDroid (and MonoTouch) were free, but they didn't go that route.

Comment: Although, the TouchQode App is not so versatile, this answer is the most relevant.

Comment: The one I was looking for has sourceLair. It's another app. To be honest, though, on-device development tools are still a new thing for Android. I think given the power of recent devices we'll be seeing a bit more of it.

Answer (score 2):

Why not, it's a linux kernel and a well supported architecture (arm). You can compile GCC for android, but the performance of a tablet will not amaze you. You will also need to build glibc I guess - you can check here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1299962

Basically you will need to cross compile gcc and glibc for the arm architecture.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any free C++ and/or C# compiler that runs on any Android-enabled Tablet PC?

Let's pretend, for the moment, that the answer was yes (it's certainly not for C#).

You would also need:

- the Android SDK and its toolchain
- the Android NDK (since you are interested in C/C++) and the rest of its toolchain
- the IDE

None of that exists to run on Android at this time, though there are some OK text editors.

Comment: He wants to compile on the Android, not for the Android

Comment: He said you need the SDK/NDK/IDE _on_ Android. That's not actually true (for C/++, all you need is a toolchain, a la the NDK) but it's still not a misunderstanding the question. Also, his comment about C# is true because no free port exists that I know of. But it's all possible.

Comment: @MerickOWA: The only reason to run a compiler on Android is to write code for Android. If the OP simply wants to edit C/C++/C# code, all you need is an editor.